# Drupal 7: Have an Edit Field within a Viewed Node

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, field

I have a content type which is only viewable (not editable) to a certain role. I've customised the form output completely (manually outputting each field as they display in a certain way).

However there's **one field** I would like this user to be able to 'edit' which is a custom 'revision comment' field I've made. I can hardcode in the form fields, except of course it won't work without the token, build id etc that Drupal generates like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="<?php print render($form['#build_id']); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php print drupal_get_token($form['#token']); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php print render($form['#form_id']); ?>">
```

So essentially I'm wondering what workaround I could use, as $form and it's variable are obviously only generated when 'editing' the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs to know, I hardcoded this into the template file and it works:

```
<form class="node-form node-project-form" action="/dashboard" method="post" id="project-node-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="nid" value="<?php print $nodeid; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?php print $user->uid; ?>">
  <div id="revision-comments" style="margin:0">
    <label for="log-comments">Log Message</label>
    <textarea id="log-comments" name="log_comments"" cols="60" rows="4" class="form-textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Post Comment" class="form-submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why didn't you use Drupal's [FAPI](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)? You can use code to select which parts of the form to output.

Comment: I would do things differently now, I had a lot of trouble taming Drupal's inner workings. I just came across this old question of mine from a year ago, and thought I'd post what I did back then.